# How to use `html()` to insert text into an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display "00:00" on the page but the page is empty I don't know why it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var minut = $("#minut").html;
    var mid = $("#mid").html;
    var sec = $("sec").html;
    minut = "00";
    mid = ":";
    sec = "00";
});
```

HTML

```
<span id="minut"></span>
<span id="mid"></span>
<span id="sec"></span>
```

Comment: var minut = $("#minut"); 
minut.html("00"); 
try like this for all variables , you need to select the selector alone to change the html . Not the html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.text()` to display text within the div you are querying... Check out snippit

You were also missing a `#` symbol in your `sec` selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 let minut = $("#minut");
 let mid = $("#mid");
 let sec = $("#sec");
 minut.text("00");
 mid.text(":");
 sec.text("00");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="minut"></span>
<span id="mid"></span>
<span id="sec"></span>
```